# Free Mailitem in Delphi

Tags: delphi, outlook-addin, pascal

I have a Mailitem and make a reply for that.
Now I register an OnSend EventHandler and display the Item with modal FALSE.
Everything works as desired.
My Problem is that I don't know how to free the MailItem.
If I display the Item modal I can free it in the finally block at the end of the function, 
but if I display the Item non-modal, my eventhanlder (AOnSend) clearly will never be called, cause the mailitem with the registered handler is thrown away.
But to simply not call MailItem.Free will produce a Mem-Leak, so my Question: How to correctly free this MailItem?

```
function InternalReply(AFolder, AMailID, ASender, ACC: String; AWithoutTo: TList<String>; AModal: Boolean; AOnSend: TMailItemSend; var AErrorText: String; AReplyAll: Boolean = FALSE): Boolean; overload;
var AOutlookApplication: TOutlookApplication;
    ANewInstance: Boolean;
    AMAPIFolder: MAPIFolder;
    AMailItem: MailItem;
    AMail: TMailItem;
begin
  AErrorText := '';
  AOutlookApplication := Nil;
  AMailItem := Nil;
  AMail := TMailItem.Create(Nil);
  try
    try
      Result := OpenOutlookInstance(AOutlookApplication, ANewInstance, AErrorText);
      if Result then begin
        AMAPIFolder := IntGetFolderByName(AOutlookApplication, UpperCase(AFolder), AErrorText);
        if Assigned(AMAPIFolder) then begin
          Result := IntGetMailFromMAPIFolderByID(AOutlookApplication, AMAPIFolder, AMailID, AMailItem, AErrorText);
          if Result and Assigned(AMailItem) then begin
            AMailItem := AMailItem.ReplyAll;
            if Assigned(AOnSend) then begin
              AMail.ConnectTo(AMailItem);
              AMail.OnSend := AOnSend;
            end;

            if Assigned(AMailItem) then begin
              ...
              AMailItem.Display(AModal);
            end
            else begin
              Result := TRUE;
            end;
          end
          else begin
            Result := FALSE;
            AErrorText := AErrorText + ' Mail not found! MailID: ' + AMailID;
          end;
        end
        else begin
          Result := FALSE;
          AErrorText := AErrorText + ' Folder not found! Name: ' + AFolder;
        end;
        CloseOutlookInstance(AOutlookApplication, ANewInstance, AErrorText);
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do begin
        Result := FALSE;
        AErrorText := AErrorText + ' ' + 'Reply: Internal Error! Message: ' + E.Message;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    AMail.Free // IF I DO THIS THEN I LOSE MY HANDLER
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you are working in a class, you would need to create and free `AMail` in the `constructor` resp. `destructor`.

But since `InternalReply` is not part of a class, you would need to create and free it in the `initialization` and `finalization` of your function. It is then a variable in the `implementation` section of your unit. Does this help or do you need a new `AMail` at every function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a global object container for this purpose: `TObjectList`.

When you create a new mail, add it to the container.
In the OnSend eventhandler, you can remove the mail from the container.
If you work like this, you can have multiple mails open at the same time:

```
uses
  Contnrs,
...

var 
  Mails : TObjectList;
...

// create the container at application startup
// do not forget to free the container at application termination
 Mails := TObjectList.Create; 

...

// create mail
function InternalReply()
...
 if Assigned(AOnSend) then begin
  AMail.ConnectTo(AMailItem);
  AMail.OnSend := AOnSend;
  // add it to the container
  Mails.Add(AMail); 
 end;
...
end;

// in your OnSend handler, remove mail from the list
// this will automatically free the mail
procedure AOnSend(Sender: TObject; var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
 ... 
 Mails.Remove(Sender); // sender is our Mail object
end;
```